# Which memory segment is this string is stored in C language?

Tags: c, string, memory

```
char *s = "Hello world";
```

In which memory segment should this string be stored (stack, heap, etc.)
using the C language?

Comment: The C language doesn't specify how data is stored, that's an implementation detail.

Comment: The pointer is usually stored on the stack, the text itself in the text section.

Comment: String literals have static storage duration.  "Stack" and "heap" are not C-language concepts.  C does not define different kinds of memory (though it does not insist that all memory be the same, either).  In implementations for stack-based machines, storage for objects with static duration is not ordinarily on the stack.

Comment: The storage duration for the pointer, on the other hand, depends on where its declaration appears.

Comment: C Standard only says *what* the code should do, not *how* it should do it. Optimising compilers may use any means possible if the result is the same. The C standard does not mention any heap or stack.

Answer (score 0):

The string literal has a lifetime that spans the entire program invocation. The object may be used anywhere in the program at any time between startup and termination, wherever a pointer to it is made known.

This means that in practice, it is placed into some storage that is allocated together with the program. Compiled programs carry these literals in their image, so space is allocated for them when the program is loaded into memory.

Programs prepared in read-only memory (ROM) may have the literals in that ROM together with the program, directly accessed in-place.